# Is there any alternate method for 'connect by ' in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I am looking for an alternative to `CONNECT BY`:

```
Select SUBSTR(str,1,LEVEL) OUTPUT FROM
(
    SELECT 'ORACLE'  As str FROM DUAL
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(str);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the issue with using a `connect by`?  We can suggest alternatives like, say, a pipelined table function.  But without knowing what problem you're trying to solve, it's very very difficult to guess at what alternatives will be better for you rather than worse.

Answer (score 6):

Several options:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/230250/1)

**Query 1 - Use a collection**:

The values are hard-coded here so this probably isn't the best solution unless you have a fixed length list.

```
SELECT SUBSTR( 'ORACLE', 1, COLUMN_VALUE ) AS value
FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/230250/1/0)**:

```
|  VALUE |
|--------|
|      O |
|     OR |
|    ORA |
|   ORAC |
|  ORACL |
| ORACLE |
```

**Query 2 - Use a pipelined function to generate a collection**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_numbers (
  maximum IN NUMBER
) RETURN SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST PIPELINED AS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. maximum LOOP
    PIPE ROW(i);   
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
/

SELECT SUBSTR( 'ORACLE', 1, COLUMN_VALUE ) AS value
FROM   TABLE( get_numbers( LENGTH( 'ORACLE' ) ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/230250/1/1)**:

```
|  VALUE |
|--------|
|      O |
|     OR |
|    ORA |
|   ORAC |
|  ORACL |
| ORACLE |
```

**Query 3 - Use a non-pipelined function to generate a collection**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_numbers2 (
  maximum IN NUMBER
) RETURN SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
AS
  v_nums SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST();
BEGIN
  v_nums.EXTEND( maximum );
  FOR i IN 1 .. maximum LOOP
    v_nums(i) := i;   
  END LOOP;
  RETURN v_nums;
END;
/

SELECT SUBSTR( 'ORACLE', 1, COLUMN_VALUE ) AS value
FROM   TABLE( get_numbers2( LENGTH( 'ORACLE' ) ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/230250/1/2)**:

```
|  VALUE |
|--------|
|      O |
|     OR |
|    ORA |
|   ORAC |
|  ORACL |
| ORACLE |
```

**Query 4 - Use Recursive Subquery Factoring**:

```
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT 'ORACLE' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR( value, 1, LENGTH( value ) - 1 )
  FROM   data
  WHERE  LENGTH( value ) >  1
)
SELECT * FROM data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/230250/1/3)**:

```
|  VALUE |
|--------|
| ORACLE |
|  ORACL |
|   ORAC |
|    ORA |
|     OR |
|      O |
```

Answer (score -3):

SELECT
RPAD(LPAD('ORACLE',ROWNUM,'ORACLE'),7) AS GRAPH
from emp
where rownum <7

Answer (score -3):

Here is a pyramid programme.

SELECT
RPAD(LPAD('ILOVEYOU',ROWNUM,'ILOVEYOU'),9)
   ||LPAD(RPAD('ILOVEYOU',ROWNUM,'ILOVEYOU'),9)LOVEGRAPH
FROM EMP 
WHERE ROWNUM<9
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM(SELECT RPAD(LPAD('ILOVEYOU',ROWNUM,'ILOVEYOU'),9)
||LPAD(RPAD('ILOVEYOU',ROWNUM,'ILOVEYOU'),9)LOVEGRAPH
FROM EMP
WHERE ROWNUM<9
ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC)
/

### LOVEGRAPH

I                I
IL              IL
ILO            ILO
ILOV          ILOV
ILOVE        ILOVE
ILOVEY      ILOVEY
ILOVEYO    ILOVEYO
ILOVEYOU  ILOVEYOU
ILOVEYOU  ILOVEYOU
ILOVEYO    ILOVEYO
ILOVEY      ILOVEY
ILOVE        ILOVE
ILOV          ILOV
ILO            ILO
IL              IL
I                I

16 rows selected